# baobab - kinda mushy lower trunk

Tags: houseplants

I have planted an baobab (adansonia gregorii) about a year ago. It has grown quite a lot, and the leaves have fallen off at autumn. I am patiently waiting for him to regrow, but i have noticed that the lower trunk is a bit mushy/squishy. Is this normal for this baobab?
I should probably also note that during late autumn we forgot to water it and the uppermost part has dried off. I also have a question about when exactly do baobabs sprout their leaves after winter? Thanks a lot.[image: where the squishiness is]

[image: the mushyness]